# AWS CLI - Get required permissions to execute specific command

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-iam

When creating specific role/policy to assume for some pipelines which execute aws cli commands. So my questions is, are there any way to figure out which permissions are required to execute some aws cli commands?

For example, which permissions are required to be part of the role to perform an Elastic Beanstalk environment update with `aws elasticbeanstalk update-environment`?

Comment: This might help: [Using Elastic Beanstalk with AWS IAM](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/AWSHowTo.iam.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using [iamlive](https://github.com/iann0036/iamlive), which allows you to generate IAM policies from AWS calls.